# How to map quotations in flex?

Tags: c, flex-lexer

How can you map a quotation mark in flex? such as:

```
""" {return ' " ';}
```

I have tried the method above and it doesn't seem to be accepting that as a rule.

I have also tried

```
"\"" {return ' " ';}
```

this has also not worked.

Comment: use raw string prefix(optional) R "delimiter( raw_characters )delimiter" . http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: `"\""` should work fine. Do you have a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"\"" {return ' " ';}
```

Isn't legal *C*. You need to return `'"'`, without the spaces. It's only a single character you're matching. You coud also try:

```
["] return '"';
```

but in fact I prefer to omit all single special-character rules and just have

```
. return yytext[0];
```

at the bottom of the grammar. That way yiou don't have thousands of rules for `+`, `-`, etc. etc., and incidentally illegal characters become parsing errors and can be error-recovered from.